# Solve analytically a delayed differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following delayed differential equation

$$G'(t)=\Lambda +\omega G(t-\tau)-\mu G(t),$$

when $G(t)=G_0>0$ for $t\in[-\tau,0]$ and $\Lambda,\omega, \mu, \tau>0$. **Note that $G_0, \Lambda, \omega, \tau, \mu$ and final time $T_f$ are arbitrary.**

I tried to solve it using Wolfram Mathematica 11.0 with code

`sol=DSolve[{G'[t]==a+b*G[t-d]-u*G[t], G[t/;t<=0]==G0}, G[t], {t, 0, Tf}]`

and I didn't receive the solution.

Can somebody help me?

Thank you very much!
Ana

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
d = 1;
Tf = 1;
DSolve[{G'[t] == a + b*G[t - d] - u*G[t], G[t /; t <= 0] == G0}, G[t], {t, 0, Tf}];

(* {{G[t] -> Piecewise[{{G0, t <= 0},
{(-a + a*E^(t*u) - b*G0 + b*E^(t*u)*G0 + G0*u)/(E^(t*u)*u), 
  Inequality[0, Less, t, LessEqual, 1]}}, Indeterminate]}}*)
```

`DSolve` needs a value for `d`(better exact) and `Tf` to solve. If you don't gives then MMA can't solve or gives a `Error` messages.

**EDITED -27.04.2018.**

Using Laplace transfrom to eq:

```
eq = G'[t] == a + b*G[t - d] - u*G[t];
eq2 = LaplaceTransform[eq, t, s] 

(* -G[0] + s LaplaceTransform[G[t], t, s] == 
a/s - u LaplaceTransform[G[t], t, s] + 
b LaplaceTransform[G[-d + t], t, s] *)
```

in the last expression MMA can't find transform [of LaplaceTransform(G[t - d], t, s) see page 120](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007060231X) (it's 
 weakness of this function) and puttting initial condition `G[0]=G0`

```
eq3 = -G[0] + s LaplaceTransform[G[t], t, s] == a/s - u LaplaceTransform[G[t], t, s] + 
b *Exp[-d*s]*LaplaceTransform[G[t], t, s] /. G[0] -> G0

sol = LaplaceTransform[G[t], t, s] /. Solve[eq3, LaplaceTransform[G[t], t, s]][[1]]
(* (E^(d s) (a + G0 s))/(s (-b + E^(d s) s + E^(d s) u)) *)
```

Inverse Laplace Transform:

```
Total@(InverseLaplaceTransform[#, s, t] & /@ {(sol // Apart)[[1]], (sol // Apart)[[2]]})

(* a/u + (E^(-t u) (-a + G0 u))/u + 
b InverseLaplaceTransform[(a + G0 s)/(
s (s + u) (-b + E^(d s) s + E^(d s) u)), s, t]*)
```

MMA can only find for first experssion.

Comment: I understood your suggestion, but I want to solve the differential equation for an arbitrary $\tau>0$ and for all final time $T_f>0$...

Comment: As I said, `DSolve` can't solve for arbitrary `d` and `Tf`.`DSolve` have some limitations. Putt your questions to https://math.stackexchange.com maybe will help you there.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, putting my question in [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com).I'm going to analyze your previous edition (27-04-2018). Thank you!